# Drawing Line From an Angle in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt

First of all, I must say this is a repost. My previous post was marked a duplicate, and in spite of me quite clearly saying in an edit why this was nothing like the other one, it seems nobody would visit it anyway. The question is still perfectly valid and completely unanswered, so please don't mark it a duplicate simply because someone else was also making a game with Pacman. If my method of rectifying this is wrong, please forgive me and show me the correct way to fix such an issue, as I still have very little knowledge of how this site functions.

My previous post is below:

I'm creating a Pacman themed pong game. To add to the theme, I would like to draw two lines at the angle that Pacman is facing, one on either side of the ball. I am putting everything in a single JPanel, as I have not reached the point in my education that uses components. I attempted to create a corridor object that takes arguments from my Pacman, but I do not know how to do the trig. My frame is 1000 by 1000, with a bar at the top 40 pixels tall for displaying data. My Pacman gives info in degrees, so please account for that in answers. Thank you, and I will do my best to answer any questions.

UPDATE: I've done some work, and I've got some code to share on this topic. It is below:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Corridor
{
public Corridor()
{

}
public void drawLines(Graphics myBuffer, BallPacman pm)
{
double x1 = pm.getX();
double y1 = pm.getY() + 150;
double ix = pm.getdx();
double iy = pm.getdy();
double x2 = pm.getX();
double y2 = pm.getY() + 150;
    if (iy < 0) {
        while (x1 > 0 && y1 > 40) {
            x1 -= 0.1;
            y1 -= 0.1 * (iy / ix);
        }
        if (x1 <= 0)
        {
            y1 += (0 - x1) * (iy / ix);
            x1 = 0;
        }
        else {
            x1 += (40 - y1) * (iy / ix);
            y1 = 40;
        }
        while (x2 < 1000 && y2 < 1000) {
            x2 += 0.1;
            y2 += 0.1 * (iy / ix);
        }
        if (x2 >= 1000) {
            y2 -= (x1 - 1000) * (iy / ix);
            x2 = 1000;
        }
        else {
            x2 -= (1000 - y2) * (iy / ix);
            y2 = 1000;
        }
    }
    else {
        while (x1 > 0 && y1 > 40) {
            x1 -= 0.1;
            y1 -= 0.1 * -(iy / ix);
        }
        if (x1 <= 0)
        {
            y1 += (0 - x1) * -(iy / ix);
            x1 = 0;
        }
        else {
            x1 += (40 - y1) * -(iy / ix);
            y1 = 40;
        }
        while (x2 < 1000 && y2 < 1000) {
            x2 += 0.1;
            y2 += 0.1 * -(iy / ix);
        }
        if (x2 >= 1000) {
            y2 -= (x2 - 1000) * -(iy / ix);
            x2 = 1000;
        }
        else {
            x2 -= (y2 - 1000) * -(iy / ix);
            y2 = 1000;
        }
    }
    myBuffer.setColor (Color.BLUE);
    myBuffer.drawLine ((int)x1, (int)y1, (int)x2, (int)y2);
}
}
```

Unfortunately, this produces odd results, such as moving and perpendicular lines. I realize it only produces one line, but it is meant as a test. BallPacman has a move method which moves it by dx and dy every time a timer is called. dx and dy may be positive or negative.

UPDATE: I asked a friend of mine, who said that essentially, what I want is to have two lines parallel to the line which Ballpacman follows. Unfortunately, I don't know how to achieve this result.

UPDATE: I would like to post some new and additional code: 
The method I used to get the angle (input dx and dy):

```
public double getFAngle (double x, double y)
{
    return Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x, y));
}
```

A new strategy I attempted to use to get the line (present in the drawLines method):

```
double angle = pm.getFAngle (pm.getdx(), pm.getdy());
int x1 = (int) (pm.getX() + 5000 * Math.cos (angle * Math.PI / 180));
int x2 = (int) (pm.getX() - 5000 * Math.cos (angle * Math.PI / 180));
int y1 = (int) (pm.getY() + 5000 * Math.sin (angle * Math.PI / 180));
int y2 = (int) (pm.getY() - 5000 * Math.sin (angle * Math.PI / 180));
myBuffer.setColor (Color.BLUE);
myBuffer.drawLine (x1, y1, x2, y2);`
```

This method was an attempt to make a line that would go straight through Pacman's path. My thinking was that if I could do that, I could achieve the walls by simply increasing and decreasing the y points for lines 1 and 2, respectively. It worked seemingly perfectly in every multiple of 90, including 0. However, it worked in a very odd way for all the other angles. The only specific I can provide for this is that it became perpendicular at 45 degrees. In addition, the lines were moving, which was not desirable in the least. This code also compromised my desires to have the endpoints directly on the walls. Allow me to elaborate on the aims of my program:

1. Sense the correct angle of Pacman
2. Draw two lines parallel to Pacman's path, so that Pacman will not
   intercept with them at any point. Preferably, these lines will have
   endpoints on at least two of the following four lines: x = 0, x =
   1000, y = 40, y = 1000
3. Draw the same lines regardless of Pacman's X & Y. In other words, the lines should not change due to any change of Pacman's progression along the path.
4. When Pacman's angle changes, the lines will change to reflect that change. It does not matter whether the calculations are run every call, as long as the correct result, static(nonmoving) lines with the correct angles, is present.

Thank you.

UPDATE (on repost):
My best code has not changed since the last update. However, I have given some thought to why it doesn't work, and have produced the following hypothesis: It is working just as horribly on the 90 degree multiples as it is on every other angle. However, the nature of the angles prevents me from seeing that the line is moving. As such, I must guess that the code is flawed because it possesses no way to ignore the movement of Pacman.

UPDATE:
In response to requests for pictures that I have received multiple times, I have this [rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3PiD.png) from one of the few angles that VGR's excellent code works in.
As I said, the code works in multiples of 90 degrees, such as the one above, but does not render properly for all other angles. And in response to VGR's comment, they never move when Pacman's x and y change (because they shouldn't have to), but will move in response to Pacman changing angle. Think of the lines as the walls of a `Corridor` that always moves to where Pacman needs to go. They'll never move as Pacman goes down the hallway, but as soon as he reaches a dead end, the corridor shifts to fit his new heading. I sincerely hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the right idea:

```
Shape originalClip = myBuffer.getClip();
myBuffer.clipRect(0, 40, 1000, 1000 - 40);

double x = pm.getX();
double y = pm.getY();
double angle = Math.atan2(pm.getdy(), pm.getdx());
double dx = PACMAN_RADIUS * Math.sin(angle);
double dy = PACMAN_RADIUS * Math.cos(angle);

double x1 = x - dx;
double x2 = x + dx;
double y1 = y - dy;
double y2 = y + dy;

myBuffer.setColor(Color.BLUE);

myBuffer.drawLine((int) (x1 - 5000 * dy),
                  (int) (y1 + 5000 * dx),
                  (int) (x1 + 5000 * dy),
                  (int) (y1 - 5000 * dx));

myBuffer.drawLine((int) (x2 - 5000 * dy),
                  (int) (y2 + 5000 * dx),
                  (int) (x2 + 5000 * dy),
                  (int) (y2 - 5000 * dx));

myBuffer.setClip(originalClip);
```

Some notes:

- [clipRect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#clipRect-int-int-int-int-) is used to make sure the lines don't draw above y=40.
- There is no point in converting to degrees only to convert back to radians.
- [atan2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2-double-double-) expects *dy* as the first argument and *dx* as the second argument.

Comment: A few things:
First of all: Thank you! This is by far the most helpful response I have ever gotten on this community. Second, I attempted to implement your note that atan2 accepts dy as the first and dx as the second in my code, but nothing seems to work. I had to offset by 90 in my fillArc method when I had dx as the first argument, but that was completely reliable. No matter what variation I try, dy as the first argument produces unseemly results.

Comment: On the topic of the main focus, the two lines render very well, and they fill the requirements of code aim #4 perfectly, as well as #2 partially. Quite possibly, #1 is fit as well, but there is no visually conclusive way to deduce that. The problems are that: 1) The lines are visually moving, and 2) The lines are most certainly not tailored to Pacman's angle. While Pacman most certainly does not touch the lines (thus partially fulfilling #2), this is because the lines are constantly in motion in an effort to move beyond his reach. What are possible causes for this?

Comment: It's difficult to understand your goal.  If the lines never move, where do you want their endpoints to be?  If they never move, how can they be parallel to the Pac-Man when it changes direction?  Perhaps you can create an image showing an example of the desired behavior?

Comment: If the update doesn't answer your questions, please tell me what is required.

Comment: You say the lines “never move when Pacman's x and y change (because they shouldn't have to),” but I don't understand how that's possible.  If the corridor is always surrounding Pac-Man, how can it *not* move when Pac-Man moves?  If Pac-Man moves horizontally for a while, then moves up by ten pixels, then starts moving horizontally again, doesn't the horizontal corridor now need to be drawn ten pixels higher than before?

Comment: Pacman only moves forward. It will never move in the direction it is not facing, and it will only change the direction it is facing when it hits a wall. When it hits a wall, this will be the instant when the walls change position again to the naked eye. The walls are never shifting (as in, they will never change position every frame), but they do change position in a manner that appears instantaneous visually.

Comment: Let me clarify the comment above: the first two occurrences of the word "walls" refer to the borders of the game. Following that, every use of the word "walls" refers to the `Corridor`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent code. It would have worked perfectly if not for an error on my part: atan2 works in a standard coordinate grid, with (0, 0) at the center, and infinity approaching up and to the right. However, Graphics in java work with a coordinate system with (0, 0) at the top left, with infinity approaching down and to the right. As such, the one thing wrong with your code was simply accommodating for this, I.e. `-pm.getdy()`.